# How do I install when I dont get the option to write to disk

Tags: system-installation

I am running window 7 I want to setup a dual boot, I do not get the option to write to disk how can I setup a CD with out it?

Answer (score 1):

You can burn the Ubuntu iso into a thumb drive and then setup your BIOS to boot from USB. That's what I always do. I haven't use CD/DVD for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to install from a flash drive.  Then I think you need to press F12 while starting up and it will give you the option to boot from the flash drive you made.